# TimeoutError when using Infura websocket with web3.py

Tags: web3.py, infura, websocket

When I run the following code sometimes it executes successfully, but most of the time it raises a `concurrent.futures._base.TimeoutError`. What can I do to fix this?

Here is the code:

```py
infura_url_ws = 'wss://mainnet.infura.io/ws/v3/MY-PROJECT-ID'
ws3 = Web3(Web3.WebsocketProvider(infura_url_ws))

abi = [{"name": "NewExchange", "inputs": [{"type": "address", "name": "token", "indexed": True}, {"type": "address", "name": "exchange", "indexed": True}], "anonymous": False, "type": "event"}] 
uniswap = ws3.eth.contract('0xc0a47dFe034B400B47bDaD5FecDa2621de6c4d95', abi=abi)

events = uniswap.events.NewExchange.createFilter(fromBlock=8567919).get_all_entries()
block_number = events[0]['blockNumber']
print(block_number)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try limiting the amount of blocks to 1000

https://community.infura.io/t/getlogs-error-query-returned-more-than-1000-results/358/6

A infura dev mentions:

We currently limit response to blocks of 1000 responses, https://infura.io/docs/ethereum/json-rpc/eth_getLogs 90, the limitations are outlined in this doc.

Limiting the amount of blocks worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

web3.py requires the parameter `websocket_timeout=60` for a  WebsocketProvider:

```py
from web3 import Web3
w3 = Web3(Web3.WebsocketProvider("ws://127.0.0.1:8546", websocket_timeout=60))
```

If you're using HTTP, you set `request_kwargs={'timeout':60}` instead:

```py
from web3 import Web3
w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider("http://127.0.0.1:8545", request_kwargs={'timeout': 60}))
```

Documentation:
https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/providers.html

Answer (score 0):

Any too large response from commercial node providers will time out, because their servers cannot handle the request due to it blocking other customers.

- [Learn how to batch your event log requests with web3.py](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html#advanced-example-fetching-all-token-transfer-events)
- [Run your own Ethereum node with unlimited JSON-RPC requests](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html#advanced-example-fetching-all-token-transfer-events)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
ws3 = Web3(Web3.WebsocketProvider(infura_url_ws,request_kwargs={'timeout':60}))
```

If I remember correctly, the default timeout is 10 (seconds).

Comment: Thanks. I tried, but it still does not work.

Comment: @Nate: What version of web3.py are you using?

Comment: How long does it wait now before throwing timeout error?  Probably you just need to increase timeout even further?

Comment: This is incorrect syntax for a websocketprovider. see https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/providers.html